# How to add up the inputted scores to allow dividing the total by the "count" to get an average?

Tags: python

The goal is to collect grades from 5 different students by calling their name and then getting a grade average while using the first for-loop,
and then collecting student scores by using another for-loop.

```
print('Lets get a class average of yesterdays quiz.')
students=['Mary','Edith','Sybil','Matthew','Tom']
for student in students:
    print(student,'What was your score?')
    sum=''
    sum=int(input('My score was a '))

print('Great.')

# The count of all the students
count=0
for itervar in ['Mary','Edith','Sybil','Matthew','Tom']:
    count=count+1
print('Number of scores:',count)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could initialize a variable `total` to 0 and add the inputs as they're provided in the loop. 
I'm not sure why you used another for loop for the count, `len(students)` should do the same job. I've used that method to get the count in this case after which the average was calculated.

```
print('Lets get a class average of yesterdays quiz.')
students=['Mary','Edith','Sybil','Matthew','Tom']
total = 0
maxscore = float('-inf')

for student in students:
    print(student,'What was your score?')
    score = int(input('My score was a '))
    if score > maxscore:
        maxscore = score
    total +=score


print('Great.')

#the count of all the students
count = len(students)
print('Number of scores:', count)
print('Average:', total/count)
print('Max Score :', maxscore)
```

You could also do `total+=int(input('My score was a '))` instead of using the `sum` variable if you just want to calculate the sum.

Comment: no need for a "sum" variable in this case. You could have just done total += int(input('My score was a ')). Other than that, great answer

Comment: That worked out great! Thank you. I also need to find the largest (value)grade out of the inputs from each score. I must find the largest using a loop. Is there some way this could be added to the existing program?

Comment: @Caldazar I figured it would be easier to understand if I could separate out the input from the summation. Will mention it within comments though. Thanks!

Comment: @Kayla Included an if condition to check the max score too. A variable was first initialized with a min value and if the input score given was greater than the max score, we update the maxscore to that value.

Comment: Once again thank you! It all worked out! Now I can rest my brain. :)